# amqp ssl connection error

Tags: ssl, mule, amqp

Hi I am trying to create a very simple AMQP connector to talk to my localhost RabbitMQ server using SSL. Without SSL, the connection works fine but I suspect my SSL configuration is incorrect. Can anyone shed light on this? I'm quite a newbie to Mule so apologies if this is ridiculous.

```
</ssl:connector>
<flow name="here_we_go_againFlow1">
    <amqp:inbound-endpoint exchangeName="sales_exchange" queueName="sales_queue" responseTimeout="10000" exchange-pattern="request-response" connector-ref="AMQP_0_9_Connector" doc:name="AMQP-0-9" ref="AMQP_0_9"/>
    <ssl:outbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="5671" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SSL (TLS)"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Made several changes to all this and am using AMQPS with a keystore and truststore. Now I have a different issue and I think I need to explicitly declare SASL_MECHS to be EXTERNAL but I cannot do this. This is because I receive the following in the log <cn=qpid_dummy>

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are trying to connect to an AMQP server over SSL. Here is an example using the ampqs transport. Note the namespaces etc.

```
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:amqps="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqps" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqps http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqps/current/mule-amqps.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <amqps:connector name="amqpsDefaultSslConnector" />

    <flow name="amqp">
        <amqps:inbound-endpoint exchangeName="target-exchange"
         exchangeType="fanout" exchangeDurable="true" exchangeAutoDelete="false"
         queueName="target-queue" queueDurable="true" queueAutoDelete="false"
         queueExclusive="true" routingKey="a.b.c" connector-ref="amqpsDefaultSslConnector" />

     ....
     </flow>
</mule>
```

There's also more advanced configuration such as setting up key stores etc. Examples can be found here: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-transport-amqp/blob/master/mule-transport-amqp/src/test/resources/amqps-namespace-config.xml